# How to tell if cURL Module is enabled

Tags: curl

How do you check to see if you have cURL enabled? I have tried to install using `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` as well as `sudo apt-get install php7-curl` both show that they read package list, build dependency tree, and reading state information but then display

```
E: Unable to locate package phpX-curl
```

where `X` is 5 or 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu 16.04, you can install the CURL module for PHP 7 by running `sudo apt install php-curl`.